# postgres select aggregate timespans

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table with the following structure:

```
timstamp-start, timestamp-stop
1,5
6,10
25,30
31,35
...
```

i am only interested in continuous timespans e.g. the break between a timestamp-end and the following timestamp-start is less than 3.

How could I get the aggregated covered timespans as a result:

```
timestamp-start,timestamp-stop
1,10
25,35
```

The reason I am considering this is because a user may request a timespan that would need to return several thousand rows. However, most records are continous and using above method could potentially reduce many thousand of rows down to just a dozen. Or is the added computation not worth the savings in bandwith and latency?

Comment: can there be overlaps in start and end times?

Comment: no, there are no overlaps. I hope this makes it a little easier :) @vkp

Comment: Cross post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156945/postgres-select-aggregate-timespans

Comment: Cross post here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922859/sql-stored-procedure-to-recognice-timestamp-overlap-and-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the time stamps in three steps:

1. Add a flag to determine where a new period starts (that is, a gap greater than 3).
2. Cumulatively sum the flag to assign groupings.
3. Re-aggregate with the new groupings.

The code looks like:

```
select min(ts_start) as ts_start, max(ts_end) as ts_end
from (select t.*,
             sum(flag) over (order by ts_start) as grouping
      from (select t.*,
                   (coalesce(ts_start - lag(ts_end) over (order by ts_start),0) > 3)::int as flag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grouping;
```